# 403 issue on reactjs app hosted on private s3 bucket behind cloudfront

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following setup:

1. ReactJS app hosted on s3 static web hosting, with error redirection to `/index.html`
2. the bucket has public access disabled
3. the cloudfront connects to the bucket via the static web hosting endpoint
4. the cloudfront already has OAD enabled

The bucket has a policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::workflow-builder.lotusflare.net/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxxx:distribution/xxxx"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Where the xxxx values above represent AWS id and cloudfront id respectively.

I also have the cloudfront to connect to custom error page that for 403 errors, redirect to `/` with 200 response code.

However with the above setting, the cloudfront url still gets 403.

If I turn on bucket's public access, the cloudfront will work successfully, however, I have to put the bucket behind public access.

I am wondering what is missing, or what are the process to verify?